# Map values from dictionary's list to a string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nlp

I am working on some sentence formation like this:

```
sentence = "PERSON is ADJECTIVE"
dictionary = {"PERSON": ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol"], "ADJECTIVE": ["cute", "intelligent"]}
```

I would now need all possible combinations to form this sentence from the dictionary, like:

```
Alice is cute
Alice is intelligent
Bob is cute
Bob is intelligent
Carol is cute
Carol is intelligent
```

Can we also make this scale up for longer sentences?

Example:

```
sentence = PERSON is ADJECTIVE and is from COUNTRY 
dictionary = {"PERSON": ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol"], "ADJECTIVE": ["cute", "intelligent"], "COUNTRY": ["USA", "Japan", "China", "India"]}
```

This again provides all possible combinations

Comment: Use two nested loops.

Comment: @Shubhashish , I am a newbie, could you please post a logic, this would also scale up, any capital letters would have a list of values in the dictionary to fetch from

Answer (score 2):

You can do this,

```
dictionary = {"PERSON": ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol"], "ADJECTIVE": ["cute", "intelligent"]}

for i in dictionary["PERSON"]:
    for j in dictionary["ADJECTIVE"]:
        print(f"{i} is {j}")
```

Output:

```
Alice is cute
Alice is intelligent
Bob is cute
Bob is intelligent
Carol is cute
Carol is intelligent
```

Here in the outer loop iterate through each of the `elements` of the `list` having key PERSON and the inner loop iterate through the `element` of the `list` having key `ADJECTIVE`. being inside the outer loop the inner loop repeat itself for each `element` of the first list/list with key `PERSON`.

Edit regarding your question update:

You can use another loop inside the inner loop, like this.

```
dictionary = {"PERSON": ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol"], "ADJECTIVE": ["cute", "intelligent"], "COUNTRY": ["USA", "Japan", "China", "India"]}

for PERSON in dictionary["PERSON"]:
    for ADJECTIVE in dictionary["ADJECTIVE"]:
        for COUNTRY in dictionary["COUNTRY"]:
            sentence = f"{PERSON} is {ADJECTIVE} and is from {COUNTRY}"
            print(sentence)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful, but do we have any other way where we can scale up the same for longer sentences? Example: `sentence = PERSON is ADJECTIVE and is from COUNTRY` and `dictionary = {"PERSON": ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol"], "ADJECTIVE": ["cute", "intelligent"], "COUNTRY": ["USA", "Japan", "China", India]}`. This should essentially provide all possible combinations from the dictionary.

Comment: @BalajiSrinivasan This should be asked in a new question with the focus on what you try to and some more details. Actually question do not deal with that fact.

Comment: @BalajiSrinivasan use another loop for `COUNTRY` is side the inner loop/second loop, like this,        

for k in dictionary["COUNTRY"]:
        print(f"{i} is {j} and is from {k}")

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in sentence:
  for y in dictionary:
    print(x, y)
```

something like this?

Comment: Please improve your answer it looks more like a comment.